# How to select a SysListView321 item?

Tags: c#, listview, autoit-c#-wrapper

For an integrated ListView named SysListView321 I can select an item with AutoIt:

```
ControlListView($Wnd,"","SysListView321","Select",15,0)
```

But the only way to confirm the selection is to point it with the mouse pointer and click the left button. How to do this manipulation automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Autoit forum, I recieved the following code which is working perfect:

```
Local $hWnd = WinActivate("Name Window")
WinWaitActive($hWnd)
Local $hCtrl = ControlGetHandle($hWnd, "", "SysListView321")
_GUICtrlListView_ClickItem($hCtrl, 15)
```